# Перечисление однородных несогласованных определений

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены

Нужны ли запятые в данном предложении? Понятно, что автор хотел подчеркнуть перечисление, но мне кажется, здесь можно обойтись и без запятых...

В настоящее время равномерно продается вся наша продукция, всех типоразмеров, из разных марок сталей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) В настоящее время равномерно продается **наша продукция** всех типоразмеров, из разных марок сталей.

2) В настоящее время равномерно продается **вся наша продукция** - всех типоразмеров, из разных марок сталей.

3) В настоящее время равномерно продается **вся наша продукция**: всех типоразмеров, из разных марок сталей.

Варианты 2 и 3 включают обобщюющее слово "вся наша продукция", поэтому ствится тире или двоеточие.

Comment: Да, действительно, я не подумала об обобщающем слове. Но все-таки исходный вариант, мне кажется, тоже имеет право на существование, если рассматривать _всех типоразмеров, из разных марок сталей_ как дополнение или уточнение...

Comment: Да, исходный вариант можно тоже оставить. В этом случае мы имеем обособленный ряд из двух определений со значением уточнения.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Умение видеть нестандартные варианты - это очень здорово.